# want to implement merge sort algorithm in different way

Tags: algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic, mergesort

Merge Sort divide the list into the smallest unit (1 element), then compare each element with the adjacent list to sort and merge the two adjacent list. Finally all the elements are sorted and merged.
I want to implement the merge sort algorithm in such a way that it divides the list into a smallest unit of two elements and then sort and merge them. ? 
How i can implement that???

MERGE-SORT (A, p, r)

1. IF p < r                                                    // Check for base case
2. THEN q = FLOOR[(p + r)/2]                 // Divide step
3. MERGE (A, p, q)                          // Conquer step.
4. MERGE (A, q + 1, r)                     // Conquer step.
5. MERGE (A, p, q, r)                       // Conquer step.

something like p < r+1 .

Comment: "something like p < r+1". I don't think this will work. If you have 3 elements in an array, it is split in to two arrays of size 1 and 2. So, Merge-Sort is doing what you want in the second array. Also, I don't understand how you are going to do this "differently" by having base element as 2 instead of 1. Merge-Sort accounts for both cases in its original form.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something that sounds this before.  Here are 2 variations.

Variation 1: Go through the list, sorting each pair.  Then go through the list, merging each pair of pairs.  Then each pair of 4s, and so on.  When you've merged the whole list, you're done.

Variation 2: Have a stack of sorted arrays.  Each element merges into the bottom array, and then cascade, but merging down until there is only one, or the second from the top is larger than the top.  After your last element has been added, collapse the array by merging it.

The case where I've used variation 2 was one where I had a very large amount of data streaming in.  I kept the first few stacks of sorted arrays in memory, and then later ones stored on disk.  This lead to good locality of reference, and efficient use of disk.  (You ask why I didn't use an off the shelf solution?  Well the dataset I had coming in was bigger than the disk I had to handle it on, there was custom merging logic in there, and the sort really wasn't that hard to write.)